# broadcast live audio to mobile devices with lowest posible latency

Tags: ios, http, audio, mobile, streaming

I need to send audio of a translator(person) in real time (or as close as posible) to mobile phones so attendees can "tune in".

I looked at Icecast server (was too laggy), WebRTC(IOS 5 needs to be supported) and am now looking into node.js with binary streaming. I also considered an FM Transmitter, but Iphones don't have FM Radio.

I can capture the audio data and send it to server and transcode in realtime (MLT Framework) Just wondering what the best course of action would be? I really would like to use a browser as delivery platform.
Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this problem?